# OR_BIBED_07 error when trying to pay with Google Pay in production environment

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

When trying to pay by using Google Pay I obtain the `OR_BIBED_07` error. That happened before of starting the approval process in the Google Pay & Wallet console. I submitted the request for approval and after two days it has been approved.

The error has disappeared when using the app signed with my local production keystore. BUT, when sending it to the store or to App Tester, so when the app is countersigned with the Play Store keystore, the error pops up again... What should I do? The approval process on the Google Pay & Wallet console seems to be easy and there's not a specific check on the app certificate, so I don't understand why the same app signed with a certificate works but does not work when signing with another certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not have the app registered in the console:
https://pay.google.com/business/console/payment/YOURMERCHANTID

Go there, select your app's package name, take screenshots of the payment flow, send to review and wait for approval.

Not signing the app with the same key is also an issue.

Comment: My app has already been approved. My problem is related to the certificate used to sign the app, since the app is re-signed by Google on the Play Store

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this error involves registering the correct app ID and completing the review process. [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/730) for Stripe's React Native SDK walks through many ways to resolve this error. I recommend reading through it to determine if any of these approaches will work for you.